# How can a derivative appear in a summation?

Tags: statistics, derivatives, summation, expected-value

Example 3.19 in the 9th edition of Probability and Statistics by Jay Devore is about expected value and has the following equations:

$$
p(x) = \begin{cases}
          p(1-p)^{x-1}\ \ x=1,2,3,...\\
          0\ \ \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases}
$$
and
$$
E(X)=\sum_{D}x\cdot{p(x)}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xp(1-p)^{x-1}=p\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\big{[}-\frac{d}{dp}(1-p)^x\big{]}
$$

Where is the derivative coming from in the right-hand side of the second equation?

Comment: It's equal to $-x(1-p)^{x-1}$.  The $p$ got shuffled out front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working out the derivative inside the sum,
$$p\sum_{x=1}^\infty-\frac{d}{dp}(1-p)^x,$$
we obtain
$$p\sum_{x=1}^\infty-\left(-x(1-p)^{x-1}\right).$$
Expanding the bracket and simplifying gives
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty px(1-p)^{x-1},$$
and since $px=xp$ you get the equality as written.